# jQuery slideToggle not work on <ul>

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, slide, slidetoggle

The slideToggle function of jquery not work on my code, nothing happens..

This is my code.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="button">clickhere</a>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #45afff;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li{
  float:none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: also get chrome and use the dev tools, console will help you debug

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing `);` to close your `click` function and wrap your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    }); // <-- Here
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gn6RK/)**

Comment: Yeah, i just forget it here on stackoverflow, but i wrote in my code, not work.

Comment: Did you check my demo? Also remember to include jQuery properly and wrap your code inside DOM ready hanlder. Check my update

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be in `document.ready`

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.button').click(function() {
      $('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });  // here you missed closing tag
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sEwM6/146/)

Comment: it's strange, because i have the $(document).ready(function(){...}); but nothing happens. I tried also with the $(window).load(...) but with no luck.

Comment: @mauriziolibravene what error in your console.loaded jquery lib ?

Comment: i look at the console, and i found another part of code with a problem.. thanks so much for the support

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There was another part of another code (not related to this issue) on my script.js that has an error. sorry